# Applying styles to custom combobox

Tags: wpf

I have created control which is derived from combo box. I have a common style for every combo box in my application. The style is working fine for every combo box except the control I have created.

Please find the code for reference.

-xaml -Code For  custom combobox

```
<local:FilteredComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Height="20"       x:Name="cbBillingProvider" Padding="4 3" />
```

--c# code for custom combo box.

```
public class FilteredComboBox : ComboBox
{
}
```

-Combo box style code from combobox.xaml

```
ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BCBSKCICD10"
                mc:Ignorable="d">
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
<ResourceDictionary Source="Shared.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton"
               TargetType="{ x:Type ToggleButton}">
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
      <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
      <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
        <Storyboard>
          <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
              (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                 Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
          </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </VisualState>
      <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
      <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
        <Storyboard>
          <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
              (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                 Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlDarkColor}" />
          </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).
              (SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                 Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
          </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
              (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                 Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderDarkColor}" />
          </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
      <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
        <Storyboard>
          <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
              (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                 Value="{StaticResource ControlPressedColor}" />
          </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </VisualState>
      <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
      <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
    </VisualStateGroup>
  </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
  <Border x:Name="Border"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          CornerRadius="2"
          BorderThickness="1">
    <Border.BorderBrush>
      <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1"
                           StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
                      Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}"
                      Offset="1" />
      </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.BorderBrush>
    <Border.Background>

      <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                           EndPoint="0,1">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
          <GradientStopCollection>
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                          Offset="1.0" />
          </GradientStopCollection>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
      </LinearGradientBrush>

    </Border.Background>
  </Border>
  <Border Grid.Column="0"
          CornerRadius="2,0,0,2"
          Margin="1" >
    <Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"/>
    </Border.Background>
  </Border>
  <Path x:Name="Arrow"
        Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" >
    <Path.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource GlyphColor}"/>
    </Path.Fill>
  </Path>
</Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox"
               TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
<Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
        Focusable="False"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
</ControlTemplate>
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}"
     TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
<Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
        Value="true" />
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
        Value="true" />
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
        Value="Auto" />
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
        Value="Auto" />
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
        Value="true" />
<Setter Property="MinWidth"
        Value="120" />
<Setter Property="MinHeight"
        Value="20" />
<Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="20"></Setter>

    <Setter Property="Template">

  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
      <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
              <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).
                    (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                  <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                       Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
          </VisualStateGroup>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EditStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Editable">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                               Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                          Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                               Storyboard.TargetName="ContentSite">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                          Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Uneditable" />
          </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton"
                      Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"
                      Grid.Column="2"
                      Focusable="false"
                      ClickMode="Press"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                          IsHitTestVisible="False"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                          ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                          Margin="3,3,23,3"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        </ContentPresenter>
        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                 Style="{x:Null}"
                 Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                 Margin="3,3,23,3"
                 Focusable="True"
                 Background="Transparent"
                 Visibility="Hidden"
                 IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
        <Popup x:Name="Popup"
               Placement="Bottom"
               IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
               AllowsTransparency="True"
               Focusable="False"
               PopupAnimation="Slide">
          <Grid x:Name="DropDown"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                    BorderThickness="1">
              <Border.BorderBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
              </Border.BorderBrush>
              <Border.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
              </Border.Background>
            </Border>
            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
              <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                          KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
            </ScrollViewer>
          </Grid>
        </Popup>
      </Grid>
      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                 Value="false">
          <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder"
                  Property="MinHeight"
                  Value="95" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping"
                 Value="true">
          <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                  Value="false" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger SourceName="Popup"
                 Property="AllowsTransparency"
                 Value="true">
          <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder"
                  Property="CornerRadius"
                  Value="4" />
          <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder"
                  Property="Margin"
                  Value="0,2,0,0" />
        </Trigger>
      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  </Style>    
  <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}"
     TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
<Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
        Value="true" />
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
        Value="true" />
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
      <Border x:Name="Border"
              Padding="2"
              SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
              Background="Transparent">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
              <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                  (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                  <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                       Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
              <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                  (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                  <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                       Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
          </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <ContentPresenter />
      </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Can any one help to apply the same style in my custom combo box?

Thanks

Apurva Shah

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class FilteredComboBox : ComboBox
{
    static FilteredComboBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FilteredComboBox), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ComboBox)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I don't like this since you would have to create a new line for every inherited type you create (probably not possible) but you can always reference the default style.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:FilteredComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}"/>
```

I guess it's the same as hard coding it each time in c#